# html5 video seeking event getting called on click of play

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am using a HTML 5 video on my site. Need to capture the seeking event of the video, I have added the below code

```
videoObj.addEventListener('seeking', function(){
        seekingVideo = true;
        console.log('here');
    });
```

But it gets called even on click of the play button on load of the page. Please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Neha

Comment: _"But it gets called even on click of the play button on load of the page"_ Can we have a demo ?

Comment: I never saw this happen ; can you a jsfiddle please?

Comment: Really sorry, it was my mistake. On play I used to check where the user had reached last time. and take the user there automatically. This used to trigger the seeking event. How do I remove the above question ?